# grouping continuous data with specific pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame with a column like this (I am not posting other columns)

```
Value
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
1
2
2
0
0
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
2
2
1
1
2
0
0
1
0
```

I am trying to group it based on a specific condition. Grouping has to be done when I have 1 and 2. But conditions like these are one group :

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Basically I need to group occurrences of `1` but in between `0s` are allowed

Expected output:

```
Value   Group
    1   1
    1   1 
    1   1
    0   1
    0   1
    1   1
    0   1 
    0   1
    1   1
    1   1
    2   2
    2   2
    0   2
    0   2
    1   3
    0   3
    0   3
    1   3 
    1   3
    1   3
    0   3
    0   3
    2   4 
    2   4
    1   5
    1   5
    2   6
    0   6
    0   6
    1   7
    0   7 
    2   8
    0   8
    2   8
    1   9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, Group := .GRP, .(date, rleid(nafill(replace(Value, Value==0L, NA_integer_), "locf")))]
```

Comment: How can I group it only to two groups ? Just 1 and 2

Comment: what do you mean? pls add to your desired output

Comment: actually I wanted to get the number of times  a shift happens from 1 to 2 in the values provided in between 0s are allowed(same like the grouping criteria)

Comment: diff from what you posted in the post?

Comment: Yes... should I ask it as a new question ?

Comment: The post is about grouping only. What I am asking is for getting the number of times there is shit from 1 to 2

Comment: yeah better to post as a new qn with sample data and desired output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145772/number-of-time-group-change-has-occurred-based-on-some-conditions-in-r-data-tabl

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base approach that uses `ave()` to count the changes between `1` and `2` and then uses `cummax()` on the result to give the final groupings.

```
dat$Group <- cummax(ave(dat$Value, dat$Value == 0, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(x[1], diff(x) != 0))))

dat
   Value Group
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      0     1
5      0     1
6      1     1
7      0     1
8      0     1
9      1     1
10     1     1
11     2     2
12     2     2
13     0     2
14     0     2
15     1     3
16     0     3
17     0     3
18     1     3
19     1     3
20     1     3
21     0     3
22     0     3
23     2     4
24     2     4
25     1     5
26     1     5
27     2     6
28     0     6
29     0     6
30     1     7
31     0     7
```

In response to your comment, if you want the result by grouped by date, you can use a nested `ave()`:

```
ave(ave(dat$Value, dat$Value == 0, dat$date, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(x[1], diff(x) != 0))), dat$date, FUN = cummax)
```

Comment: How to group it with respect to each day if I have a date column?

Comment: I am getting repeating groups.

Comment: Please post your expected output - your question should be fully representative of your problem.

Comment: How can I group it only to two groups ? Just 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

This loop in Base-R does the trick

```
group <- 0
lastgroupvalue <- NA
data$Group <- NA

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(!data$Value[i] %in% c(lastgroupvalue, 0)){
        group <- group + 1
        lastgroupvalue <- data$Value[i]
    }
    data$Group[i] <- group
}

> data
   Value Group
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      0     1
5      0     1
6      1     1
7      0     1
8      0     1
9      1     1
10     1     1
11     2     2
12     2     2
13     0     2
14     0     2
15     1     3
16     0     3
17     0     3
18     1     3
19     1     3
20     1     3
21     0     3
22     0     3
23     2     4
24     2     4
25     1     5
26     1     5
27     2     6
28     0     6
29     0     6
30     1     7
31     0     7
```

---

***Data:***

```
data <- structure(list(Value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

Comment: How to group it with respect to each day if I have a date column?

Comment: You'll have to provide a representative example if you want solutions to work with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Or a tidyverse solution that avoids loops:

```
x <- tibble(Value=c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,
                    0,0,2,2,1,1,2,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,1)) %>% 
       mutate(ModValue=ifelse(Value == 0, NA, Value)) %>%
       fill(ModValue, .direction="down")

runLengths <- rle(x$ModValue)
groupIndex <- unlist(lapply(1:length(runLengths$lengths), 
                            function(x) rep(x, runLengths$lengths[x]))
                    )

x <- x %>% add_column(Group=groupIndex) %>% select(-ModValue)
```

Your input data has a different length to your expected output.  Took me a while to work that out... :)

** Edit **

And an inelegant solution to account for changing days (or other super-groupings...

```
x <- tibble(
       RowNumber=1:35,
       Date=lubridate::ymd(c(rep("2020-05-31", 20), rep("2020-06-01", 15))),
       Value=c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,1,1,2,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,1))

# Check we have a change of date mid-sequence
x %>% filter(row_number() > 15 & row_number() < 25)   

x <- x %>% 
       mutate(ModValue=ifelse(Value == 0, NA, Value)) %>%
       fill(ModValue, .direction="down")

# Inelegantly compute the groups
make_groups <- function(x) {
  runs <- rle(x)
  return(tibble(GroupWithinDay=unlist(
                                 lapply(1:length(runs$lengths), 
                                        function(x) rep(x, runs$lengths[x])))))
}

y <- x %>% group_by(Date) %>% do(make_groups(.$ModValue))
x <- x %>% add_column(GroupWithinDay=y$GroupWithinDay) %>% select(-ModValue)

# Check the change of date is handled correctly
x %>% filter(row_number() > 15 & row_number() < 25)
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  RowNumber Date       Value GroupWithinDay
      <int> <date>     <dbl>          <int>
1        16 2020-05-31     0              3
2        17 2020-05-31     0              3
3        18 2020-05-31     1              3
4        19 2020-05-31     1              3
5        20 2020-05-31     1              3
6        21 2020-06-01     0              1
7        22 2020-06-01     0              1
8        23 2020-06-01     2              2
9        24 2020-06-01     2              2
```

Comment: How to group it with respect to each day if I have a date column?

Comment: As @DanielO says, you'll need to give us some test data and sample output to answer this new question.  Will, for example, a change of date trigger a new group even if it's within a sequence of 1's?

Comment: Yes it will be new group

Comment: How can I group it only to two groups ? Just 1 and 2

Comment: Please provide an example with input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that avoids loops, that works similar to Limey's solution but uses `cumsum` to create the groups.

```
df$Group <- dplyr::na_if(df$Value, 0)
df <- tidyr::fill(df, Group, .direction = "down")
df$Group <- cumsum(df$Group != dplyr::lag(df$Group, default = -1))

> df

   Value Group
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      1     1
4      0     1
5      0     1
6      1     1
7      0     1
8      0     1
9      1     1
10     1     1
11     2     2
12     2     2
13     0     2
14     0     2
15     1     3
16     0     3
17     0     3
18     1     3
19     1     3
20     1     3
21     0     3
22     0     3
23     2     4
24     2     4
25     1     5
26     1     5
27     2     6
28     0     6
29     0     6
30     1     7
31     0     7
```

Comment: How to group it with respect to each day if I have a date column?